# Visual Studio 2017 Windows - Excessive unwanted highlighting

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I just started using Visual Studio 2017.

I switched to a dark theme, and almost every line has a lighter highlight to it, with things like @, keywords, open and close curly braces and parentheses, all highlighted. The highlighting is both light grey and yellow.

I've attached a picture for reference.

I'm running Visual Studio Community 2017. Version 15.8.1 on Windows 10

How do i get rid of this? a million thanks!

i searched google and stack overflow for answers, but the ambiguity of "highlighting" in the search made me get answers that were WAY off.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors`.

The items are `HTML Razor Code Background` (grey) and `HTML Server-Side Script` (yellow). Set `Item background` to whatever you like (e.g., set it to your normal code background color to get rid of the highlight).

Comment: That works, but when i select black as the color for the HTML Razor Code Background, it's a different black than the background? Weird. thanks!

Comment: @PeterAndrus true, in most color themes the background color isn't actually black. You can find out what your background color is in the same window, it's `Plain text`.